# Remove a specific suffix in variable names

Tags: sas

suppose to have the following dataset:

> ```
> ID       GEO    Variable_1    Variable_name_1     Variable_code_as_1
> 1         A       0.3             0.0                 1.3             
> 1         B       0.1             0.2                 1.6
> 1         D       0.22            0.5                 1.2
> 1         B       0.5             0.8                 1.4
> 1         C       0.6             0.1                 1.7
> 1         F       0.9             0.2                 1.8
> ```

Is there a way to remove "underscore 1" from variable names? I tried different codes found all around on the web but without success maybe because there are different "_" and I need to remove only the last one.
Can anyone help me please?

Edit: need to remove _1

Comment: You want to remove the last occuring '1' from all variable names in a data set, correct?

Comment: The last _1 at the end of each column name. It results from proc freq unfortunately. I have _0 and _1. I dropped columns with _0 but need to rename columns I want to retain that unfortunately end with _1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
data have;
input ID GEO $ Variable_1 Variable_name_1 Variable_code_as_1;
datalines;
1 A 0.3  0.0 1.3 
1 B 0.1  0.2 1.6
1 D 0.22 0.5 1.2
1 B 0.5  0.8 1.4
1 C 0.6  0.1 1.7
1 F 0.9  0.2 1.8
;

proc contents data=have;run;

data _null_;
   set sashelp.vcolumn end=lr;
   where libname='WORK' and memname='HAVE';

   if _n_ = 1 then 
      call execute('proc datasets lib=work nolist; modify have;');
      
   if substr(name, length(name) -1, 2) = '_1' then 
      call execute('rename ' || name || '=' || tranwrd(name, '_1', '') ||';');

   if lr then 
      call execute('quit;');
run;

proc contents data=have;run;
```

Comment: Thank you very much @PeterClemmersen. So if I understand correctly, " if substr(name, length(name) -1, 2) " does the job. Correct?